# Recover simulated affine transformation for matched asift features (Morel's implementation)

Tags: affinetransform, feature-extraction, asift

Has anyone tried to recover the simulated affine transformation for the ASIFT feature detector? (From the author's implementation). In [the original paper](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/my-asift/ASIFT_SIIMS_final.pdf) the simulated affine is clearly recovered by the equation 2.2 but I cannot seem to find a clear point where this is performed. Has anyone tried before? The function compensate_affine_coor1 in compute_asift_keypoints.cpp seems to be what I'm looking for but the scale seems to be normalized plus, the center of coordinates to perform the transformation is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is performed in function you mentioned. Center coordinates are shifted because when you rotate image, top-left corner(origin) is moved, so they have to compensate it. And scale doesn`t change at all.